# Probability that 5 students seated in a row are reseated such that none have the previous nieghbours

Tags: probability

> There are five students $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4 , S_5$ in a music class and for them
>   there are five seats $R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4,  R_5$ arranged in a row initially $S_i$ sits on $R_i$. For $j = 1, 2, 3, 4$ let $T_j$ denote the event that the students $S_i$ and $S_{i+1}$ do NOT sit adjacent to each other on the day of the examination. Then
>   the probability of the event $T_1 ∩ T_2 ∩ T_3 ∩ T_4$ is?

I brute forced my way through this question, found out all the possibilities

```
 13524
 24135
 35142
 35241
 41352  
 42513
 52143
```

Same number in the reverse order. Does a better method exist?

Comment: I would chase the cases as follows. Let $abcde$ be the exam constellation. Then (at least) one of $2,3,4$ is not at the margin, i.e. not placed on $a$, nor on $e$. Then the corresponding neighbors are almost determined: For $2$ (not marginal) we have $425$ or $524$ as subword of $abcde$, for $3$ then $135$ or $531$, for $4$ then $142$  or $241$. Now look for $425??$, $?425?$, $??425$ and reversed for the $2$, ...